# vim log4j syntax highlighter not working

Tags: bash, unix, vim

I have this vim plugin

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4111

installed. I have included the following lines for the .vimrc:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.log set syntax=log4j
```

I am getting "autocmd unknown command"

when I am running

```
. .vimrc
```

from the bash

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.` command in Bash reads the argument as a Bash script; you're executing the *Vim configuration* as a *Bash script*. Of course, Bash doesn't know the `autocmd` command, and therefore complains.

Vim will automatically read in your `~/.vimrc` on startup (cp. `:help initialization`). Just open a new Vim instance, and your new configuration will apply. You can ensure that the `.vimrc` has been read via `:scriptnames` (the file path should be listed at the start), or list your defined autocmd via `:autocmd BufRead *.log`

If you `:edit somefile.log`, you can verify that the syntax has been set via `:setlocal syntax?`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to run that command, once you will open any "*.log" file using "vim" the plugin will be used. if installed correctly.